# unable to attach an event in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am brand new to javascript..
i am reading a book called DOM SCRIPTING..

I tried to code an example but unfortunately the link shows  direct image..
What i am trying to do is  to swap images.
here is the js code

```
 document.ready = function () {
     function showPicture(pictureChoosen) {
            var source = pictureChoosen.getAttribute('href');

            var placeholder = document.getElementById('plaecehlder');
            placeholder.setAttribute('src', source);

        }

    }
```

And here is my html Code

```
   <ul>
    <li><a href="images/journee.jpg" onclick="showPicture(this);return false;">Journee</a></li>
    <li><a href="images/coffee.jpg">Coffee</a></li>

</ul>
<img id="plaecehlder" src="*" alt="" />Placeholder
```

Please tell me where i am doing wrong.. Thanks...

Comment: `document.ready = fn` sounds more like pseudo-code than vanilla JS.

Comment: Your top function only defines a function.  It doesn't execute...only define.

Comment: try without document.ready!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this:

```
document.ready = function () {

}
```

just define the function.  Since you have the function inside another, it is only in local scope and not in global scope where the `onclick` handler is looking.  Better though, would be giving the element an id:

```
document.getElementById("foo").attachEvent // IE

document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener // standards-compliant
```

[attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) documentation

---

You are probably confusing jQuery's `$(document).ready(function(){});` with normal DOM.  That is a shortcut for

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){}, false);
```

which will fall back to the window `onload` event in older browsers.  If you want to wrap everything up in a single function, you want:

```
window.onload = function() {

    function showPicture(pictureChoosen) {
        var source = pictureChoosen.getAttribute('href');
        var placeholder = document.getElementById('plaecehlder');
        placeholder.setAttribute('src', source);

    }

    document.getElementById("foo").onclick = function() {
        showPicture(this);
        return false;
    }
}
```

so that your function is defined in the same scope that you're assigning to the element.

Comment: yes Thanks, it worked but what i want the function ony after the Dom has been fully loaded. i mean enclosing inside window.onload function.Then it dosen't run?? can you tell me why??